# problem regarding radius of curvature.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential-geometry, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I am asked to prove the radius of the curvature of the curve $$y^2(a-x)=x^2(a+x)$$ at origin is $4\sqrt{2}a$.
[image: This is my solution]

I tried it like this, but $\textbf{I can't get 2 in the answer}$. I check it many times and I broke my head since I can't find where it went wrong. I won't even know whether there is a $\textbf{typo in my book}$ . **Please help me to find where it went wrong 
and correct answer for this question.**

Comment: (+1) nice hand writing. (Although I personally don't like uploaded hand written problems)

Comment: i'm sorry for that image but it take me long time if i type every thing since i study latex just some days ago@iamvengan

Answer (score 1):

The RHS of your equation (2) after implicit differentiation should have $+y^2$ instead of $-y^2.$ Also, $y'$ (even in your current formula) is defined at $x=0.$ After all the simplification, you should get $a\sqrt{2}$ as the radius of curvature.

Comment: But I say y' is undefined because we have x in both numerator and denominator, isn't it?

Comment: Also answer in my book is 4√2a

Comment: @grixorI too get the same result which you given.thanks for pointing out the error

Comment: @SathasivamK You're welcome! And y' is undefined when its denominator = 0, which is when x = a or x =  -a. I'd double check on the factor of 2.

Answer (score 1):

For the curve $c(x,y)=0$, the curvature is given by
$$
k = \frac{|2c_xc_yc_{xy} - c_x^2 c_{yy} - c_y^2 c_{xx}|}{(c_x^2 + c_y^2)^{3/2}}
$$
In your example, let
$$
c(x,y) = y^2(a-x) - x^2(a+x)
$$
Then
\begin{align}
c_x &= -y^2 - 2ax - 3x^2    \\
c_y &= 2(a-x)y             \\
c_{xx} &= -2a -6x          \\
c_{xy} &= -2y              \\
c_{yy} &= 2(a-x)
\end{align}
At $(x,y)=(0,0)$, we get
\begin{align}
c_x &= 0    \\
c_y &= 0             \\
c_{xx} &= -2a          \\
c_{xy} &= 0              \\
c_{yy} &= 2a
\end{align}
So, we get $0/0$. This suggests that there is something strange going on. So, to understand better, let's graph the curve. We get the following for $a=1$:

[image]

There are two branches of the curve passing through the origin. Which one should we use to compute curvature? In this particular example, both branches happen to have the same curvature at the origin, but this won't always be the case. So, beware when someone asks you to calculate "the curvature" at a point of a curve given by an implicit equation.

Let's use the branch that slopes upwards from left to right. It has equation
$$
y = x \sqrt{\frac{a+x}{a-x}}
$$
At $x=0$, we get
$$
y' = 1
$$
$$
y'' = \frac{2}{a}
$$
and so
$$
\rho = a\sqrt2
$$
If your book has some other answer, then your book is wrong.

Comment: So how can I solve it? We get indeterminate form (0/0),if I use this method

Comment: I don't know. That's why I didn't finish the answer. I will think some more today.

Comment: The whole question seems shakey, to me. This curve actually passes through the origin twice. So, which branch should be used to compute the curvature?? In this particular example, both branches have the same curvature, but that won't always be the case.

Comment: According to the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_curve, curvature is defined only at **regular** points, which are points where the first partial derivatives are not both zero. On your curve, the origin is not a regular point, so the curvature doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm hope you may help me to solve it sir!,I too try on my own ....